# JSF 2 Dynamic include ajax sort primefaces table not working

Tags: jsf-2

I am using Myfaces 2.1.9 and webflow 2.4.1M. I get a null pointer exception when trying to sort a datatable that is included by a dynamic include in my page.

I have a page that has a dynamic include:

Main xhtml page:

`<ui:include src="..#{config.getIncludeName[bean.selectBox.selected]}.xhtml" />`

I have 6 of these includes that can be switched using a select box. Each of these includes include a custom primefaces table (but they have the same ID, to the user it looks like it's the same table, but with different data, it's a different "form", if that makes sense). I want to change include by using the selectbox and then want to sort the table.

The decode phase is run, sortColumn is set on the datatable. But when the encode phase is run, the memory reference of the datatable is different from the datatable instance in the decode phase. The sortColumn is null in the encode phase, causing a null pointer exception to be thrown when the sorting is made.

This happens when the view is going to be rendered, in the buildView method in the FaceletViewDeclaration class. Seems like it builds the view again and when that happens the datatable component is reset.

Anyone know what might be the problem? Am I maybe using JSF in a way that I'm not supposed to?